# What should I correct in my angular app to make it run?

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

Actually I'm doing the udemy Max Scharzmuller angular course . While creating new component in my app i have compilation error like this :
[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jniDo.png)

I think , I have written everything in my code, that will this component run correctly. I add below the .ts code of component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
export class ServerComponent{
}
```

and app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone help what is the problem in this code ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Try to stop and restart Angular App.

Comment: I have recreated your setup in a new project and I don't get any errors. Try resetting your project, the error does not reside in those files.

Comment: your error is provoked by the the server.component.ts-file. Can you provide a screenshot of that (first 20 lines will do)? Thx, take care & good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you should restart Editor (VSCode...) compile and run again.

You should create a component via command line: ng g c [NameComponent] [Doc Angular Component](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview).

I think the error cause because you create a component not use CLI.

Hope it's work.

Comment: No, creating a component through the CLI is just by convenience. It makes sure that some things are appropriately connected and named and a test-file is created as well.  If each component has a certain structure, for instance some specific DI in the constructor, manually making the ts-, css- and html-files is actually more convenient. It prevents you forgetting something. In other words, your reasoning is wrong. However restarting never hurts.